# Is it possible to use nesting with css modules right now?

Tags: css, tailwind-css, postcss, css-modules

I am currently trying to use CSS Modules class and PostCSS's nesting abilities together in the same file with TailwindCSS. But when doing something like this in my `Sidebar.module.css`:

```
.sidebar {
    @apply fixed top-0 left-0 h-full w-64;
    &.closed {
     @apply w-20;
    }
}
```

Chrome's does not seem to be picked up and this warning appears in the inspector:
[Warning saying Unknown property name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0iFa.png)

So I am not sure if this is possible in the first place. Here is my `postcss.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    require('tailwindcss/nesting'),
    require('tailwindcss'),
    require('autoprefixer'),
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[This guide](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/using-with-preprocessors#nesting) and using the following `postcss.config.js` setup worked for me.

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    'postcss-import': {},
    'tailwindcss/nesting': {},
    'postcss-nesting': {},
    tailwindcss: {},
    'postcss-flexbugs-fixes': {},
    'postcss-preset-env': {
      autoprefixer: {
        flexbox: 'no-2009'
      },
      stage: 3,
      features: {
        'custom-properties': false,
        'nesting-rules': true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use module style CSS import, then follow this [doc](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/using-with-preprocessors#build-time-imports)
and please check your app settings as that.

```
// postcss.config.js
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    require('postcss-import'),
    require('tailwindcss/nesting'),
    require('tailwindcss'),
    require('autoprefixer'),
  ]
}
```

Comment: Is this needed if you are using NextJS? I thought posts came with it?